# Eigen library: Multiple errors originating in DenseBase.h

Tags: c++, xcode, eigen

I'm using Eigen in Xcode 5.1 and I get multiple strange errors (semantic issues) from the DenseBase header, e.g.:

In file included from ... (all files where I include Eigen/Dense)
...
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:278:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:68:11: error: using declaration refers into 'Base::', which is not a base class of 'DenseBase &, const Eigen::Matrix &, 6> >'
    using Base::derived;

Unfortunately, I cannot be more specific here since I don't know where these errors are coming from.

Comment: Paste _your_ code or a MCVE.

Comment: Sans a MCVE, can you at least post your includes, the error lines from your files, and the compiler arguments?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions concerning the missing information in my question. I'm aware of that but couldn't figure out a way to be more precise. I just thought that maybe this error message is somehow known even without posting more concretely about my code (which is pretty hard due to multiple files). The problem was due to a wrong function argument passing. The function needed an Eigen::RowVector but I passed a column vector, at least in Eclipse it now compiles fine.